# BackUp using .git?

Tags: git, backup

I was thinking at, for example, I have a website versioned using git (connetted to an online repo), but I m really carefull, so I want to backup my website to an USB device too, maybe with an rsync command.

What if I copy ONLY the .git folder?

In the case all got broken (pc, server and online repo) except that my precius USB device, can I completely restore my work (at the last commit) from the only .git folder?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: @torek so if in a folder with only the .git I enter the console and do "git checkout mybranch" it recreates all  files and dir structure outside the .git ?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  There are some details, such as whether `core.bare` is set in the copied `.git`.

Comment: @torek and is that a problem ?

Comment: Not usually.  You probably know if you're using a bare repository, and you can always convert bare to non-bare and vice versa.  If you're concerned that details might change in the future (which is always possible), you can use better-defined interfaces, specifically `git clone`.

Answer (score 0):

Having only the .git file will not allow you to reset everything.

You can [duplicate a repostiory](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/), but the chances of losing/damaging a USB are much higher than that of the servers (professionally managed) breaking down.

Comment: He suggested using `rsync` on his `.git` for which the cloud-storage version is already the backup, so he's suggesting an additional backup of the actual master: the cloud version is not the true master.  You are, however, correct that a USB device is probably much more likely to break.  But the sense of control is lacking with cloud storage. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using git bundle, see https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html. Thats packages it all up into a file that you can store on your USB drive or even email to yourself and back it up on your mail server or upload to google drive/dropbox/box/...